# How to sum of elements by using their ID?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, range

I have multiple range sliders with their Id. I want to sum the inputs using their ID.

1. Multiplication of range slider and the input.
2. And at the end Addition of all multiplication.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".range").on("change", function() {
    var mult = 0;
    $('.range').each(function() {
      var selector_next = document.getElementById("actualtime").value
      mult += parseInt($(this).val()) * selector_next //multply..
    })
    $("#addition").text(mult)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="actualtime"  value="2.5" disabled><br>
<input type="range" name="slider-1" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1" class="range" id="range-slider1"><span id="multiplication-1"></span><br>
<input type="range" name="slider-1" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1" class="range" id="range-slider2"><span id="multiplication-2"></span><br>
<input type="range" name="slider-1" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1" class="range" id="range-slider3"><span id="multiplication-3"></span><br>

<span id="addition"></span>
```

Also, get the multiplication value in their multiplication id of span tag.

Comment: HI, why id ? its working fine with classes

Comment: Can you illustrate what do you want ?

Comment: If you just need to add individual total you can use `$(this).next().text(parseInt($(this).val()) * selector_next)` inside each loop

Comment: It's ok to use classes, but how to get the value of particular multiplications?

Comment: Why use `getElementById` when you're using jQuery? `$('#actualtime').val()`

Comment: Replace the code as if it needs to be. I know it's wrong.

Comment: My first priority is getting the Addition of all multiplication.

Comment: Not getting an answer. I use this for <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970169/how-to-sum-of-elements-by-using-their-id?noredirect=1#comment120137592_67970169">link</a>. But here the multiplication is from one input only.

Comment: you need to use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`. and also you can take out of the loop this line `var selector_next = document.getElementById("actualtime").value` and change it to `var selector_next = parseFloat(document.getElementById("actualtime").value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply loop through the sliders and get the value and add it as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.range').on('change', function() {
    let total = 0;
    const multiplyFactor = parseFloat($('#actualtime').val());
    $('.range').each(function() {
      total += (parseFloat($(this).val()) * multiplyFactor);
    });
    
    $('#addition').text(total);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="actualtime"  value="2.5" disabled><br>
<input type="range" name="slider-1" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1" class="range" id="range-slider1"><span id="multiplication-1"></span><br>
<input type="range" name="slider-1" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1" class="range" id="range-slider2"><span id="multiplication-2"></span><br>
<input type="range" name="slider-1" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1" class="range" id="range-slider3"><span id="multiplication-3"></span><br>

<span id="addition"></span>
```

Comment: @freedomn-m he was also using `parseInt` to convert `"2.5"` that was parsing it to `2`.